# Getting numChildren for large data sets

Tags: firebase

I have a node that can potentially have tens of thousands of Children, I need to be able to just fetch the number of children it has without downloading the whole data.

From what I understand using the on('value') function and using DataSnapShot.numChildren(), will cause the whole data of that node to be downloaded first before counted.

Answer (score 3):

Using on('value') would indeed download the entire node. But you can use the [shallow](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-param-shallow) feature of their REST API to download only the keys, which you can then count.

```
curl 'https://samplechat.firebaseio-demo.com/.json?shallow=true&auth=CREDENTIAL'
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that Firebase currently has an operation to do that. You could always keep a property under the parent object that reflects the number of children and update it atomically upon the addition of a new child.

For example (in Javascript):

`var ref = new Firebase({base_url}/{parent_id}/children_count);
   ref.transaction(function(currentVal){
   return (currentVal || 0) + 1;
});`