# How can I find a node's children count without downloading the data in Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Swift&Firebase. Due to the changes in Firebase the old numChildren approach does not work.

I need a way to count the children of a particular node of my Firebase database without downloading the whole data.

Comment: There is no way to count the number of children (with the iOS SDK) of a node without downloading that node. This has been covered quite a few times before, likely better than we'll do now. I'll find a dupe.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26497677/how-to-keep-track-of-children-count-in-firebase, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32277082/getting-numchildren-for-large-data-sets, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443421/how-to-get-size-of-an-element-list-in-firebase-without-get-it-all/38444523#38444523, http://stackoverflow.com/a/23132570/209103